# Why does Android REST API calling consume more data than a webapp REST API calling

Tags: android, rest, api

[Android REST API data consumption on mobile data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2WdZ.png)
vs.
[Web-app REST API data consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS3Y2.png)

In these tests(please see the pictures), I have used same rest API(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1).

Web-app consumes: 292 bytes.

Android app consumes: 6.54 Kilo Bytes.

My main mobile application depends on mobile data. So I have tested the data consumption on mobile data in the android and found that this is significantly more than data consume in the web-end application. Can any body tell me why does android rest API calling consume more data than web-app rest API calling? And is there any good solution to reduce the data consumption on android application?

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to have a network capture to see exactly why that is the case.

My hunch is based on this [API reference for HttpRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidRxBytes(int))

> Statistics are measured at the network layer, so they include both TCP
>   and UDP usage

This implies that the count for the HttpRequest is including both *transport data layer header* and *network layer header*.

Which is where you are probably seeing the excess bytes consumed on the Android side.